# Weird resignFirstResponder behaviour with UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a textfield that is on a modally presented viewController that is inside a navigation controller, when i use

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

the keyboard hides as expected when i push return, but for some reason the whole view that the textfield is in sort of shrinks to the top left and leaves all the subviews shifted to the left. its a really simple view so im not sure what is going wrong, is there a different way to hide the keyboard that could potentially avoid this problem?

here are some screenshots

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]

ive attached the full code here: http://pastebin.com/PKMXEL4U

Comment: try using void, and dont retun anything

Comment: but then it wont comply with the UITextFieldDelegate protocol, which will make it just a normal method that wont actually be called by anything

Comment: Have you set the auto resizing property correctly in xib file?

Comment: im using storyboards, and im pretty sure the autosizing is right since this is a universal app, and it scales correctly when on ipad... but maybe ill fiddle around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok wow, weirdest symptoms for such a silly mistake, turns out i forgot to put `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` in the `viewWillAppear` it took me reconstructing the whole class and storyboard in a separate project to find that out >.<